# Display datetime in user's timezone

Tags: date-time

How do I get datetimes like publication time to be displayed in a user's given timezone? I haven't been able to find a plugin that works.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a service like [Google Timezone](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/timezone/start) you could get the users lat/lng data using geolocation then store that in a transient agains the IP address. Don't rely on the IP as users on a satellite connection like me can have the location pinged as thousands of km away.